# Can Someone Give Me A Simple COcos2d-X Particle Example?

Tags: cocos2d-x, particles, ccparticlesystem

I just want to make a CCParticleExplsion using Cocos2d-x and C++, but can't seem to find it after searching all over. 
ObjC example:

```
CCParticleSystem *firework = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] initWithTotalParticles:200];
[self addChild:firework];
[firework setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"star.png"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the ParticleTexture comes with the plist file, and the whole plist file is from the particle designer. Usually, we use

```
CCParticleSystemQuad* p = CCParticleSystemQuad::create("whatever_particle.plist");
this->addChild(p);
```

but if you wanna use the particles comes with cocos2d-x, you can check how to use them in the Test Cases that comes with the cocos2d-x framework. the file name is ParticleTest.cpp

Answer (score 1):

`CCParticleExplosion` is declared in `cocos2dx/particle_nodes/CCParticleExamples.h`.

Here's the C++ equivalent of your Objective C code:

```
CCTexture2D* texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->textureForKey("star.png");
CCParticleExplosion* firework = CCParticleExplosion::create();
firework->setTexture(texture);
```

Answer (score 0):

see the tests folder in the cocos2d-x root folder.